# Issue With Cloud Shoes

Tags: broken-age

On Broken Age I didn't realize that you needed to put the cloud shoes on the ladder, and I put them on myself.  Do I need to start all over now or is there a way to take them off?

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two pairs of cloudshoes, used for different purposes. If you put the pair you've got on yourself then it's where they're supposed to be.